# Display dynamic elements with vanilla javascript routing

Tags: javascript, html, api, dynamic, routes

I am trying to make a SPA app, trying to make routing with vanilla Javascript, navigating to About/Contact/Home works just fine, my problem is that I use an api to list products, all the products have a link that should display a single product without refreshing the page when the button is clicked, but it doesnt seem to work. I am new to this so probably I messed up somewhere, I also noticed that currentPath always remains '/', but CurrentPath is displayed correctly, but it doesn't seem to enter the if statement.

I used separate, about.js and contact.js file for their output, but of course with the dynamic elemnts these will not work as product will be undefined

A little hint would be greatly appreciated.

```js
import "./assets/styles/main.scss";
require('./index.html');

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", listAllProducts);

window.onload = function () {
    const container = document.querySelector('.grid_container');
    // Create Router
    let Router = function (name, routes) {
        return {
            name: name,
            routes: routes
        };
    };

    let myRouter = new Router('myRouter', [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'Root'
        },
        {
            path: '/about',
            name: 'About'
        },
        {
            path: '/contact',
            name: 'Contact'
        },
        {
            path: '/product/id',
            name: 'Product'
        }
    ]);
    console.log(myRouter);
    let currentPath = window.location.pathname;
    console.log(currentPath);

    window.addEventListener("hashchange", () => {
        const CurrentPath = window.location.hash;
        console.log(CurrentPath)
        if (CurrentPath === '#about') {
            container.innerHTML = about;
            console.log(currentPath)
            console.log(CurrentPath)
        } else if (CurrentPath === '#contact') {
            container.innerHTML = contact;
            console.log(currentPath)
            console.log(CurrentPath)
        } else if (CurrentPath === '#product/id') {
            alert('!');
            // let output = '';
            ui.showSingleProduct();
            console.log(CurrentPath);
            console.log(container.innerHTML)
        }
    });
};

// UI
class UI {
    constructor() {
        this.grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
        this.container = document.querySelector('.grid_container');
    }
    showProducts(products) {
        let output = '';
        products.forEach((product) => {
            output = output + `
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card_image_container">
                        <img src="${product.image}" alt="${product.name}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card_title">
                        <a href="#product/${product.id}" class="card_title_text" id="${product.id}">${product.name}</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card_price">&#36; ${product.price}</div>
                </div>
            `;
            console.log('works')
        });
        this.grid.innerHTML = output;
    };

    showSingleProduct(product) {
        let output = `
            <svg class="back_icon">
                <use xlink:href="#lnr-arrow-left-circle"></use>
            </svg>
            <div class="details_container">
                <div class="details_image_container">
                    <img src="${product.image}" alt="${product.name}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <h2 class="details_title">${product.name}</h2>
                    <p class="details_description">${product.description}</p>
                </div>
                <button class="add_to_cart_btn">Add to cart</button>
            </div>
        `;
        this.container.innerHTML = output;
    }
};


// HTTP requests
class CustomHTTPMethods {
    async get(url) {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
    }

    async post(url, product) {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(product),
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
    }

    async put(url, product) {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(product),
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
    }

    async delete(url) {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
            },
        });
        const data = await 'The product was succesfully deleted!';
        return data;
    }
}

const ui = new UI();
const http = new CustomHTTPMethods();
const productsURL = "https://61363d1a8700c50017ef54c1.mockapi.io/products";
const gridContainer = document.querySelector('.grid_container');


// const routes = {
//     '/': homePage,
//     '/about': aboutPage,
//     '/contact': contactPage,
//     '/products:id': productPage
// };
// gridContainer.innerHTML = routes[window.location.pathname];

// function navigate(pathName) {
//     window.history.pushState({}, pathName, window.location.origin + pathName);
//     gridContainer.innerHTML = routes[pathName];
// };
// window.onpopstate = () => {
//     gridContainer.innerHTML = routes[window.location.pathname];
// };

// document.querySelector('.navbar_list_item_link').addEventListener('click', navigate('/about'), false);




function listAllProducts() {
    http.get(productsURL).then((products) => {
        ui.showProducts(products);
    })
}
```

Comment: I see that `ui = new UI()` is called before the `onload` event, therefore `ui.grid` and `ui.container` may be undefined. Furthermore the `currentPath` variable is defined once `onload` and never updated, therefore it never changes.